# asp.net core "framework-dependent deployment" with dotnet framework

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

As I noticed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/) we have two type of deployments: "Framework-dependent deployment" and "Self-contained deployment".

But it didn't describe how to get "Framework-dependent deployment" on net451.

How I can get "Framework-dependent deployment" on net451?

Here is my project.json:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-AdsProject-110defb3-febe-4379-a8a3-0a8b20607a27",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "StackExchange.Redis": "1.1.605",
    "Dapper": "1.50.2",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Abot": "1.5.1.50"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "config.json",
      "config.Development.json",
      "web.config"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "bower_components",
      "SqlScripts",
      "PrivateJs",
      "**.xproj",
      "**.user",
      "**.vspscc"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle", "npm install" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: you already have it.

Targeting `net451`, you setup the target framework as .NET Framework 4.5.1, and it must be installed on target machine using the .NET Framework redistributable (Dotnetfx.exe) before installing your application. In other words .NET Framework application is always framework-dependent.

On the other side, Self-contained deployments (SCD) relates only to .NET Core Framework, and allows to deploy framework together with app:

> For a self-contained deployment, you deploy not only your app and any third-party dependencies, but the version of .NET Core that you build your app with.

Comment: When I publish the the project, dotnet generates also a .exe file. As article said, .exe file generates in SCD mode.
"SCDs include an executable (such as app.exe on Windows platforms for an application named app)" and "FDDs contain .dll files that can be launched by using the dotnet utility from the command line"

Comment: I don't want .exe file. I have to stop application in production every time I want to publish project.

Comment: .exe is generated as your target framework is .NET Framework, that knows nothing about .NET Core Platform and so you have "old type" standalone app (suggest to read this post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/ ). Regarding "stopping during publishing" - you anyway need to restart process if you change assemblies... Maybe you mean to use dotnet-watch, but it also restarts the specified application when changes in the source code are detected.